# group by day of week and another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to group by two columns. day of the week and another second column. but I don't know How should I do this.
It is my query for one column:

```
grouped = (df.groupby(df['time'].dt.weekday_name)['id'].count().rename('count'))
```

Where should I add the second column? for example "type" column in my dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.groupby()` takes a list, like this:

```
df.groupby([df['time'].dt.weekday_name, df['type']])
```